# How to configure java message box button

Tags: java, jdialog

i have create JOptionPane to display simple yes/no dialog box. But i have no idea how to configure my Yes/no button output.

```
public static void button1(){

  //Custom button text
Object[] options = {"Yes",
                    "No",};

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
"Do you want cake?  ",
"Cake",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null,
options,
options[1]);

}
```

Desired Output :

```
JOptionPane box prompt Yes and No button
if user mouse click ok button display system.out.printf("I Like Cake, Yes")
otherwise system.out.printf("I dont like cake, no")
```

my current code only display jdialog message with default yes and no button. but do not have meaningful function currently.

My Tutorial Reference : [Oracle Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: does that means the message box is working but the message after clicking yes/no is not displaying. **OR** explain it clearly if something else

Comment: i want to create a message box with ok button and no button. Ok button will just simply output "i like cake " statement. and so for No button, "I dont like cake". Current code after i click ok or no button it will exit. Thank you for asking.

Comment: I just learn about how to create java message box from oracle tutorial but i still not clear how to put instruction on button

Comment: see my answer below..

Comment: what do you meant by saying how to put instruction on button....

Comment: instruction like the answer you have given just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`showConfirmDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-), intead of `showOptionDialog`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int cake =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
             "Do you want Cake?", "Cake", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

       if (cake == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
           System.out.println("I Like Cake, Yes");
       } else if (cake == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
           System.out.println("I dont like cake, no");
       }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [`JOptionPane API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). They give example usages of the different `showXxxDialog`

Comment: Yes, your answer is much more neat and structured. Your code deserve to be rate as answer.

Comment: @Prakash who said the OP wanted values other than yes/no?

Answer (score 3):

Add this code at last in your function.

```
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("I Like Cake");
    } else if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println("I dont like cake");
    }
```

Comment: Oh so actually Joptionpane button will return 0 or 1. now everything is clear. thanks @Prakash

Comment: Not Joptionpane.It is a class.The value is returned by it's method showOptionDialog.The returned datatype differs for other methods like showInputDialog ,showMessageDialog methods in Joptionpane class..